# Cakephp 3 i18nFormat to show date or date-time

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

I'm using CakePHP 3. I have a table with two fields in my Mysql database, one of DATE type and another of DATETIME type.

I want to show them in my views as a simple date or as a date-time with 'dd/mm/yyyy' or 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm', but also depending on **i18n**.

I've tried many combinations and constants but can't get the expected result. For example, if I have this:

```
$this->Time->i18nFormat($date, \IntldateFormatter::SHORT);
```

...and I apply this to a date and datetime values, it will return respectively:

**2/7/15 0:00:00 (GMT)   -- Date field**

**13/7/15 10:00:00 (GMT)    -- Date-Time field**

...and what I would like is:

**02/07/2015  -- Date field**

**13/07/2015 10:00 -- Date-Time field**

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forgot to say that in previous version of CakePHP (2.6) I could do this using Time helper with format '%c' for date-time and '%x' for simple date, but it's not working in CakePHP 3.